# jfm-style pop-up when hoverin figure and citations

Tags: graphics, citing

Take this example: 
http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/jfm.2015.335 
It is a random (recent) paper from journal of Fluid Mechanics.It should be on open-access at this moment.

If you open it with acrobat reader (currently on Windows, cannot say about Linux readers), when you hover with the mouse over a reference to a figure or a citation a "pop-up" appear with the figure or the citation itself.

How can I achieve the same effect?

NO MWE because it is not related to a specific problem, but more a general question about how to do it.

Anyway, example are welcome!

Comment: If you want example code, provide a basic document with a couple of hyperlinks that people can use as a basis. Don't expect people helping you to create a suitable example from scratch: they should just have to complete the example to provide the feature you are asking for help with. However, if you just want a general pointer in the right direction, that's different and I've added an answer on that assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't provide an MWE, it seems you are not looking for code. So I take it you just want a general pointer.

The general approach is to use a package such as [cooltooltips](http://ctan.org/pkg/cooltooltips) to enable pop-ups associated with hyperlinks.

Comment: It is enough. I ll try by myself and in case I ll prepare a detailed question!

Comment: @thunder1123 Fair enough! Once you try it, if you do get stuck, you'll at least know what you need help with specifically. That always makes things easier. (Both for writing questions and answering them!)